# How to user PHP library without composer on webspace?

Tags: php, composer-php, spl-autoload-register

php 5.4

[Library apai-io](https://github.com/Exeu/apai-io)

This lib is created with composer. But I cannot use composer on my webspace.

I googled it and the answer was to include an autoloader function and register it with spl_autoload_register.

I have tried not been able to get anything to work with autoload funtions.

I don't know if I had to replace namespace and use from scripts or replace them with `spl_autoload_register` or both.

```
namespace ApaiIO;

use ApaiIO\Configuration\ConfigurationInterface; 
use ApaiIO\Operations\OperationInterface;
use ApaiIO\Request\RequestFactory;
use ApaiIO\ResponseTransformer\ResponseTransformerFactory;
```

Can somebody explain me (maybe with source code) what I need to do to get the library running?

**(UPDATE)**

- dowloaded XAMPP & Composer
- added depency to composer.json
- run composer install
  --> lib was added
- uploaded the whole vendor folder
- wanted to start example of lib

-->error:

> You must set up the project dependencies, run the following commands: `curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php php composer.phar install`

**Question:**
Do I have to add the autoload.php in folder vendor to any script?

Comment: _But i cannot use composer on my webspace._ - why? what's the problem?

Comment: Why can't you install the package on your local machine before you upload to shared hosting?

Comment: Just upload the `/vendor` folder as well to your hosting and it should work?

Comment: First you create yourself a local web server so you can install everything and have absolute control over what is installed on your site. Then you FTP it all to the LIVE server

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: Reformat explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add following code to your php file

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
```

Answer (score 1):

Like everybody said in the comments on the main post, install your library on you local machine and just copy the /vendor directory that composer makes for you to your production server.